# Android Studio выдает ошибку при загрузке нового проекта

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio выдает ошибку: Rendering Problems
(Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout ?)
В чем проблема то ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK861jVtsKI

Comment: После настройки темы выдает еще больше ошибок:                                                one or more layouts are missing the layout width or layout height

Comment: Вы хотя бы выложите свою разметку, а то как всегда, штатный экстрасенс в отпуске